# Java android laser barcode scanner

Tags: java, android, usb, barcode

I am trying to develope an application wich is able to read barcodes (1d not qr). The real problem is that the common barcode reader softwares are very useful but they appears to be too slow to use as a very frequent and common feature (these barcodes are quite long 20-30 digits and it seems to be too big for applications like zxing). So i need to use a physical laser barcode scanner but i dont know the first clue where to start. I also have an old laser barcode scanner to test with. As far as i understand from that device manual it does not requires any driver only sends data as strings to the buffer of the keyboard but yet i was not able to make it work. All of the manuals i found are focusing on qr codes and software based scanning. Any idea or link would be helpful that i can use to learn about these things.

Comment: AFAIK all you need is USB host support on the phone to connect a physical bar code scanner but not sure if phone can power it

Comment: "2d not qr" - should this perhaps be "1d not qr"? Linear barcodes are 1D, QR and various other types are 2D

Comment: yes sorry and Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have just (yesterday) successfully tested the following combination:

Nexus 7 +

USB OTG cable ( [[Aftermarket Product] Brand New Micro USB Host Mode OTG Cable Flash Drive SD T-Flash Card Adapter FOR Samsung GT-i9100 i9100 Galaxy S II 2 GT-N7000 Galaxy Note](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B005FUNQXS/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=B005FUNQXS&linkCode=as2&tag=tonpus-21) )  +

USB laser barcode scanner (available here: [USB Automatic Barcode Scanner Scanning Barcode Bar-code Reader with Hands Free Adjustable Stand (Black)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B005DJS29O/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=B005DJS29O&linkCode=as2&tag=tonpus-21)  ).

Works great !! However, sometimes the apps themselves are a bit slow on taking keyboard data (as they don't expect it to arrive so fast), so just be wary of that.

I rooted my N7 ... but I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Should have mentioned.... not sure about how draining on the battery it is so do watch out for that.

Comment: Question... with the barcode scanner attached, does the android keyboard still work? I can get the barcode scanner to work, but then there is no keyboard. Unplug the scanner and the keyboard returns. Anyway to get both functional. I'm using the same basic setup except that I have a Taotronics barcode scanner.