# Detect laser scanner event and get data in android K63

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I am using below device to scan the bar code using laser scanner:

```
Device Name : K63
Android : 11
```

I have checked and read [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106456/java-android-laser-barcode-scanner), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69643509/is-there-a-way-to-detect-programmaticaly-laser-scanner-in-an-android-mobile) and [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585811/android-honeywell-dolphin-how-to-detect-laser-scanner) some other questions also but not getting exactly that how to get scan event and data in the mobile device. I would like that once user scan any bar code then show that data on screen's UI so how to detect event or data.

Comment: Without a manufacturer I can only guess that there is a SDK which would allow for scanning and obtaining the lsaer barcode data. I would inspect the device for a manufacturer and check the manufacturer site for any developer SDK.